# diff --horizon-lines=lines explained

Tags: diff

I found both these quotes on the same `diff`option `--horizon-lines=lines`:

> Do not discard the last lines lines of **the common prefix and the first
>   lines lines of the common suffix**. [[source]](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#diff-Options)

The quote above links to the next quote here for more explaination:

> The `--horizon-lines=lines` option prevents `diff` from discarding the
>   last lines lines of the **prefix** and the first lines lines of the
>   **suffix**. [[source]](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#diff-Performance)

Can someonebody please explain what this might mean? Especially "the common **prefix** and the first lines lines of the common **suffix**"

Answer (score 4):

This explanation seems to make more sense then the above 2 that you cited.

*excerpt - https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff-Performance.html*

> Normally diff discards the prefix and suffix that is common to both
>   files before it attempts to find a minimal set of differences. This
>   makes diff run faster, but occasionally it may produce non-minimal
>   output. The --horizon-lines=lines option prevents diff from discarding
>   the last lines lines of the prefix and the first lines lines of the
>   suffix. This gives diff further opportunities to find a minimal
>   output.
>
> Suppose a run of changed lines includes a sequence of lines at one end
>   and there is an identical sequence of lines just outside the other
>   end. The diff command is free to choose which identical sequence is
>   included in the hunk. In this case, diff normally shifts the hunk's
>   boundaries when this merges adjacent hunks, or shifts a hunk's lines
>   towards the end of the file. Merging hunks can make the output look
>   nicer in some cases.

The reference to "lines lines" means X number of lines. So mentally read that sentence again but say "X lines" where it says "lines lines". The X would correspond to a number that was passed as an argument to `diff --horizon-lines=lines`.

The 2nd paragraph I cited above explains what the difference would be with that option specified.

Comment: A really good answer to this question would explain when the option makes a difference. It looks like a weird corner case.

Comment: @slm So basically it shortens the output? What confuses me starts in the first line of the quote: If there is something common it can't be different at the same time - or did I miss something?